# Android room: Can calling value on LiveData be used to return plain data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

Let's say I have a room DAO function `getForIdLiveData(id: String)` which returns `LiveData<SomeClass>`.

Is it save (and how is it performance-wise) to use `someClassDAO.getForIdLiveData(id).value` instead of making a duplicate DAO function which returns just `SomeClass`?

This would save a ton of boilerplate code (as the DAO functions are typically passed on through repository in MVP or MVVM) and it appears to be working so far. I just couldn't find much information of possible future complications which I (of course) want to avoid.

Example:

Can I use this:

In `someDataClassDAO`

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_id = :id")
    fun getForIdLiveData(id: String): LiveData<SomeDataClass>
```

In `MyRepo` interface

```
    getMyInfoLiveData(id: String): LiveData<SomeDataClass>
```

In `myRepoFactory` which implements custom interface `MyRepo`

```
    @WorkerThread
    override fun getMyInfoLiveData(id: String)
        = someDataClassDAO.getForIdLiveData(id)
```

In `myViewModel` class

```
    // Provide LiveData for ongoing UI display
    fun provideMyInfoLiveData(id: String) = myRepo.getMyInfoLiveData(id)

    // Get some parameter for different id (one time)
    fun getOneParameter(id): Long {
        val entity = myRepo.getMyInfoLiveData(id).value
        return entity.someField
    }
```

Instead of:

In `someDataClassDAO`

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_id = :id")
    fun getForIdLiveData(id: String): LiveData<SomeDataClass>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_id = :id")
    fun getForId(id: String): SomeDataClass
```

In `MyRepo` interface

```
    getMyInfoLiveData(id: String): LiveData<SomeDataClass>
    getMyInfo(id: String): SomeDataClass
```

In `MyRepoFactory` which implements `MyRepo`

```
    @WorkerThread
    override fun getMyInfoLiveData(id: String)
        = someDataClassDAO.getForIdLiveData(id)

    @WorkerThread
    override fun getMyInfo(id: String)
        = someDataClassDAO.getForId(id)
```

In `myViewModel` class

```
    // Provide LiveData for ongoing UI display
    fun provideMyInfoLiveData(id: String) = myRepo.getMyInfoLiveData(id)

    // Get some parameter for different id (one time)
    fun getOneParameterForId(id): Long {
        val entity = myRepo.getMyInfo(id)
        return entity.someField
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain the question a little bit more? You want you DAO to return plain data instead of `LiveData`?

Comment: Yes, without having to reroute another function through repo. I added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it save (and how is it performance-wise) to use
>   `someClassDAO.getForIdLiveData(id).value` instead of making a duplicate
>   DAO function which returns just SomeClass?

It has nothing to do with "performance-wise", it just flat-out ***wouldn't work***.

`LiveData<T>` is evaluated asynchronously when there is an active observer.

`T` is evaluated synchronously and returned immediately (I/O access, blocking).

So you'd just get null and things wouldn't work at all. You do need the two methods.

I prefer to call them `getForIdWithChanges` instead of `getForIdLiveData` considering you do know it's a LiveData from the type system.

Answer (score 0):

If you need both variants (LiveData and normal result) ypu should make 2 variants of the method in DAO. Everything else is a hack.